# how to load an image from url in balckberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Images from URL in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049101/show-images-from-url-in-blackberry)

Hi am trying to laod an image directly from url in balckberry. there is no option in balckberry to call directly. is something there to do so.kindly guide me.

Comment: check my answer of this question-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049101/show-images-from-url-in-blackberry/12049139#12049139

Comment: hai thanks for your code it just worked awesome ,but again how i will cast that to bitmap image.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut to do so. 
You need to do it by code.

```java
public static InputStream getInputStream(String url)
{
     InputStream inputStream = null;
     HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
     try
     {                        
         httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url+connectiontype));
         httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
         final int r=httpConnection.getResponseCode();
         if(r==200)
             inputStream = httpConnection.openDataInputStream();
     }
     catch(final Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println("Error is "+e.getMessage());
     }
     return inputStream;
}
```

and use `getInputStream()` like this:

```java
InputStream is=getInputStream(s1);
int length=is.available();
//System.out.print("length ==========="+length);        
byte[] data=new byte[length];

data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);

// code to save image in sd card
saveFile.create();
OutputStream outStream = saveFile.openOutputStream();
outStream.write(data);
outStream.close();
saveFile.close();
is.close();
```

This code will save image from url.